# QuickSort when the range of data is known

Tags: quicksort, constraint-satisfaction, comparison

In QuickSort Algorithm, the pivot is chosen as the first element or a randomised element. However, if the range of data to be  sorted is known, For example, from 1 to 100, and they are mostly equally distributed, then, the best choice for first pivot would be 50, even if it's not present in the array, then, for left sub-array the best pivot would be 25 and for right sub-array it would be 75, and so on.

Is there a better sorting algorithm for such distributed data in a given range? Will such QuickSort be more efficient than any other Algorithm for such data?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort

Comment: @Dmitry Will Bucket Sort be more efficient? In ideal case, each pivot will divide it into half, maybe it will be more efficient than O(n) which Bucket sort provides.

Comment: During the first partition, you may find the greatest item below 50 to be 46: better to split $[1, 50)$ or $[1,46]$?

Comment: @greybeard Pivot is just a guess, 50 is the center of the range, so, that must be the best guess.

Comment: @AbhishekChaudhary, it's impossible to be faster than $O(n)$. Also, the best possible running time for quick sort is $\Theta (n \log n)$.

Comment: @Dmitry For bucket sort, it is O(n+k) for 1 to 100, if we have 10 buckets, O(n*log n) is comparable to O(n+k), And most important, Bucket Sort is not very space efficient, Quicksort would be ideal for such data with space constraints and a little trade-off in efficiency.

Comment: You can use [counting sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort).

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Range can be very big, it's just that it is known, counting sort might use array of size 100.

Comment: I wouldn’t call an array of size 100 *big*.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus When referring to algorithms, it is considered big, especially in very limited conditions, compared to QuickSort which has O(1) space complexity.

Comment: Quicksort doesn't have $O(1)$ space complexity. At best, it has $O(\log n)$ space complexity, since the stack also consumes space. Moreover, in conditions where an array of size 100 is too much, you are probably better of using insertion sort, which is faster on small arrays.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Array of Size 100 was an example, it could be 100K elements with data between 1 and 1000, in that case, counting sort might be helpful, but in best case, O(n*log n) time and O(log n) space complexity provided by Quicksort is good enough and is most probably, more efficient overall compared to other Algorithms.